# How can Scons be setup to output directories above where the sconstruct is?

Tags: scons

I have a folder structure similar to the following:

Project
-----src
--------lib
-----bin
--------Debug
-----scons

My sconstruct and sconscripts are in the "scons" folder. What I would like to do is take the build output from my lib folder and place it into the bin/debug folder. I've tried doing something like this:

**Sconstruct:**

```
VariantDir('../bin/Debug','.')
lib = SConscript('libSconscript')
```

**Sconscript:**

```
env.StaticLibrary('../bin/Debug/lib', Glob('../src/lib/*.cpp'))
```

But that does not seem to work. From the man page, it sounds like VariantDir() would work as I've done it, but it does not seem to. If anything, it either doesn't build at all or builds in the current directory. Anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

I apologize if any of this is confusing. Keeping track of all these directories in a sconscript is more difficult than one would think it would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently SCons doesnt support this. The SConstruct has to be at the root level of the project. That is, you will need to do the following:

```
Project
-----SConstruct
-----src
--------lib
-----bin
--------Debug
```